# "Failed Invocation of APOC NLP Procedure in Neo4j Community Edition"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, nlp, neo4j-apoc, apoc

I am encountering an issue while trying to use the APOC NLP GCP plugin with Neo4j Community Edition. Instead of using the Desktop UI, I am running Neo4j in a browser due to some UI-related problems. I have downloaded Neo4j Community Edition version 5.11.0 for Windows from this link: https://dist.neo4j.org/neo4j-community-5.11.0-windows.zip.

The problem I am facing is that I want to use the `apoc.nlp.gcp.graph` method for natural language processing (NLP) tasks, but it doesn't seem to be available in the APOC plugin. When I write my Cypher query, I do not get IntelliSense for 'gcp' under 'nlp'; only 'azure' is shown.

I have manually placed the following plugins in my Neo4j plugin folder:

- apoc-5.11.0-core
- apoc-5.11.0-extended
- neosemantics-5.7.0.0

My Java Development Kit (JDK) version is `microsoft-jdk-17.0.8.1-windows-x64`. I'm trying to follow this tutorial to build a knowledge graph using NLP and ontologies: https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-data-science/build-knowledge-graph-nlp-ontologies/.

When I run the following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (a:Article {uri: "https://dev.to/lirantal/securing-a-nodejs--rethinkdb--tls-setup-on-docker-containers"})
CALL apoc.nlp.gcp.entities.stream(a, {
 nodeProperty: 'body',
 key: $key
})
YIELD node, value
SET node.processed = true
WITH node, value
UNWIND value.entities AS entity
RETURN entity
LIMIT 5;
```

I get the following error message:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound
There is no procedure with the name `apoc.nlp.gcp.entities.stream` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

**How can I resolve this issue and make the `apoc.nlp.gcp.graph` method accessible in Neo4j Community Edition running in a browser environment?**

Answer (score 0):

As [documented](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/5/nlp/gcp/#nlp-gcp-dependencies), you also need to install the `apoc-nlp-dependencies-<version number>-all.jar` file (with the correct version number) in the `plugins` folder.

You can look [here](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/releases) for that file.